# Change style onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, addclass

I want to change a tag's style using class onclick (basically I want to change the class).
This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="menutext"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');" class="scroll">Feedback</a></div>
```

I don't know what's wrong, why it's not working!
Also I would like to make this code using JQUERY, if not possible with javascript.

Comment: [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) are jQuery methods.

Answer (score 4):

calling click event is better that inline javascript... readable and easy to debug...

try this

**html**

```
<div class="menutext"><a href="#" class="scroll">Feedback</a></div>
```

**jquery**

```
 $('.menutext a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); //to prevent the default behaviour of <a>
     $(this).parent().removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2'); 
      //parent() because i think you want to change the class of the div ...
 });
```

Comment: If you want to continue changing style on every click, you can use `.toggleClass('menutext').toggleClass('menutext2')`.

Comment: welcome... glad it helped... anyways you should always accept the post as answer if it helped you ...:).. happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write a jquery selector in your onclick-event.

```
<div class="menutext">
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:$(this).removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');" class="scroll">Feedback</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Vd4tT/) works:

```
<div class="menutext"><a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');" class="scroll">Feedback</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As what I have understand on your question, this is what you want. 
  jquery

```
   $('.childDiv').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().find('.childDiv').css('background-color','#ffffff');
     $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
   });
```

html

```
 Group 1
 <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
    Child 1
</div>
<div id="child2" class="childDiv">
    Child 2
</div>
</div>
<div id="divParent2" class="parentDiv">
Group 2
<div id="child1" class="childDiv">
    Child 1
</div>
<div id="child2" class="childDiv">
    Child 2
</div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .parentDiv{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
  width: 80px; 
  margin:5px;  
  display:relative;
}


.childDiv{
border:1px solid blue;
height: 50px;   
margin:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `jQuery` and remove the `onclick` attribute in link also:

```
$('div.menutext > a').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');
});
```